# Angular Typed Forms: How to correctly type and create dynamic fields?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-formbuilder

I have the following formgroup:

```
this.formBuilder.group<{
    id: number;
    nameDe?: FormControl<string>;
    nameFr?: FormControl<string>;
    nameIt?: FormControl<string>;
}>({
    id: value?.id || null
});
```

Focus is on the "nameXY" fields. These are added dynamically/based on conditions.

```
languages.forEach((lang) => { // languages can be ['De', 'Fr'] or ['Fr', 'It']
    const nameIdentifier = 'name' + lang;
    formGroup.addControl(nameIdentifier, new FormControl<string>(value?.[nameIdentifier] || '', Validators.required));
});
```

Now I get this error:

> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type ...

Obviously it's because `nameIdentifier` is only a string and not `'nameDe' | 'nameFr'| 'nameIt'`.

The first approach I tried was to explicitely define the type for `nameIdentifier`:

```
const nameIdentifier: 'nameDe' | 'nameFr' | 'nameIt' = 'name' + lang;
```

Then I get this error:

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"nameDe" | "nameFr" | "nameIt"'.ts(2322)

Now I'm out of ideas. :)
Are there any clean approaches without having to use tons of explicit typing?

Answer (score 1):

Try type assertion using as keyword.

```
const nameIdentifier = ('name' + lang) as 'nameDe' | 'nameFr' | 'nameIt';
```

**Or**

you can use **[FormRecord](https://angular.io/guide/typed-forms#formrecord)**

Comment: This "mutes" the error but doesn't add to type safety, right?

Comment: Yes for dynamic field it is index typed.